# Facebook authentication Claims in asp.net 5 mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am trying to get some profile data from a facebook user after authentication, from sniffing I can see that the data is coming from facebook but my

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

object has only email and name filled, I would also like to get city and birthday.

this is how my configuration looks like

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AppId = "###############";
    options.AppSecret = "###################";
    options.Scope.Add("public_profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("user_location");
    options.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
    options.Scope.Add("user_hometown");
    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebooklHandler();
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,birthday,hometown,gender";

});
```

If I remove email from my configuration, email is also gone from my info object but anything else is not working.

Answer (score 0):

By default, facebook app that you previously created, gives you rights to get users about:

- Email
- Public_profile
- User_friends

To gain more accesses, then you need to send your app for review from facebook, and explain further to them with photos and videos, how will your app use all those fatures. Go to http://developer.facebook.com, click on your app. You will have a menu on your left. Click on the third option which says: "App Review", and you will understand more of what I tried to explain.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: I think what you are saying is for live version of the app, I am in development now, and as I said in question text the information is coming (I have see it with wireshark), the only problem is that the object is not populated with data.